# WSO2 JMS Mediation

Tags: jms, wso2, message-queue, wso2-esb

I want to try a use case using WSO2 in which a message sent to a queue is sent to a sequence of queues.

Currently I am using proxyname as the inbound queue and send mediator finally sends to queue 'ONE'. now If want to send the message from queue ONE to queue TWO, I had to create another proxy.

Is it possible to create a proxy which takes the message from Queue One -> queue Two -> Queue Three -> Queue Four. All using a single WSO2 proxy service.

In terms of webservice chaining, I can use callout mediator. What suggestion I have in terms of JMS queues ?

Regards
Guru
@gnanagurus

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you want to pick a message from Q1 and send it to Q2 and pick the message from Q2 and send it to Q3 and etc.. if you are dealing with proxy services you need to have listener proxy services for each queue. But you can achieve this in a single proxy services, through WSO2 ESB's Message Store/Processors.  See a sample at [1], and you can extend this to your requirement.

[1] - http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/store_n_forward_samples.html